# Multi Store mobile says too many redirects

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect

Multi store states to many redirects to clear cookies only on mobile version

so i added the following to the .htaccess and the mobile version works again

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iPhone|iPad|iPod|MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror|Chrome|Opera\ Mini|SymbianOS|Mobile) 
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

this is a total hack, anyone has any ideas on how to properly fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try following steps:

- In the `core_config_data` table remove the value of `web/cookie/cookie_domain`
- In the `core_config_data` table set `web/cookie/cookie_httponly` to **0**.
- Clear the cache by removing the files and directories in “var/cache”.

Comment: very odd it is only happening when using chrome and clicking on the inspector i checked on actual mobile device and it loads fine. very odd tried deleting history etc. whats odd is it only happens on this site my other magento sites dont do the same thing

Comment: its a caching problem

Comment: It was cahce problem for me, I just flushed magento cache. It's funny how cache in magento causes 90% of all problems